# How can I change the cone scale pivot in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to resize a cone which is created by THREE.CylinderGeometry.
 I need to make it longer and the growing direction toward the negative z-axis while I found the direction was both negative and positive.

I do know the reason is that the scale pivot of the cone is put in it，so anyone can tell me how I can change the scale pivot of a mesh in threejs?

[image: here is the img of my question]

Answer (score 0):

```
//CYLINDER
var cyl_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var cyl_width = 1;
var cyl_height = 5;
// THREE.CylinderGeometry(bottomRadius, topRadius, height, segmentsRadius, 
 segmentsHeight, openEnded )
 var cylGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(cyl_width, cyl_width, cyl_height, 20, 1, false);
// translate the cylinder geometry so that the desired point within the 
geometry is now at the origin
cylGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, cyl_height/2, 0 ) );
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylGeometry, cyl_material);

scene.add( cylinder );
```